# Clipping or masking as polygon on another polygon (bigger area) on map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I use Leaflet to display GPX data on a map. So far so good.

A challenge is now to display an area (polygon with stroke and fill) with gap(s) on a map.

Imagine you have an area with a city. This city is inside of an polygon, but should not filled with background color and the gap must be transparent.

Exists any function or plugin for Leaflet for this requirement?
Or is it possible to assign a mask with a polygons for the generated SVG?

I hope this question is not so complicated.

I searched for functions and plugins. But nothing found yet.

Comment: I think a basic sketch of the expected outcome would be useful for the people that are going to answer the question.